# Appscript for get the approval status of google sheet and transfer ownership

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I Looking for a appscript for google sheet get the approval status and if the sheet is approved it will transfer the ownership to another user. I have made some script but its not work can you please check and share the ideas or feedback on it.

```
function getApprovalStatusAndChangeOwnership() {
  // Get the sheet.
  //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
  const newOwnerEmail = "New Owner Email"; // Email of user "B".
  var id, ss, dc, fm; //declare sheet, document, form

ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // selection of active sheet only
dc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();// selection of active doc only
fm = FormApp.getActiveForm();// selection of active form only
 // Get the approval status of the sheet.
  var approvalStatus = ss.getApprovalStatus().get(0).getStatus();



if (ss != null && ss != undefined){
  id = ss.getId();
  // Check if the sheet is approved.
  if (approvalStatus == "Approved") {
    // Change the ownership of the sheet to the new owner.
    //sheet.setOwner(newOwnerEmail);
   const fileId = id; // The owner of the user of this file is user "A".

  Drive.Permissions.insert(
    { role: "owner", type: "user", value: newOwnerEmail },
    fileId,
    { moveToNewOwnersRoot: true, supportsAllDrives: true }
  );
    // Display a message to the user.
    alert("The ownership of the sheet has been successfully transferred to " + newOwnerEmail);
  } else {
    // Display an error message to the user.
    alert("The sheet is not approved yet. You cannot change the ownership of the sheet.");
  }
  }
else if (dc != null && dc != undefined){
  id = dc.getId();}
else if (fm != null && fm != undefined){
  id = fm.getId();}

 


  // Return the approval status.
return approvalStatus;
}
```

Solution for this script

Comment: Can you elaborate on what specifically is not working or what errors you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

`please check and share the ideas or feedback on it.`

With the greatest respect,

- the script cannot be checked because the concept of "approval" applies to Excel but not to Google sheets.
- notwithstanding this, the script consists of syntax errors and calls to non-extent methods.